# How to call a function component inside React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm relatively new to React and trying to learn by doing some exercises creating components & calling them. In this code segment, I created a function component `useIsFirstRender()` which will tell me if it is the first render. However, when I reference this component in the root export function `App()`, nothing renders. I am expecting it to return true or false, but right now only the text shows up. What logic am I missing here?

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export function useIsFirstRender(): boolean {
  // your code here
  const firstRender = useRef<boolean>(true);

  if (firstRender.current == true) {
    firstRender.current = false;

    return true;
  } else {
    
    return false;
  }
}

export function App() {
  const isFirstRender = useIsFirstRender();
  
  return(
    <div>
      <p>
        This is or is not the first render: {() => isFirstRender} 
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- The correct term for `useIsFirstRender` function is **custom hook**.
- Boolean values don't get rendered.

**Fix**

```
<div>
  <p>This is or is not the first render: {isFirstRender ? "is" : "is not"} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it down!

Your function is not a react component it is a `custom hook`.
The main difference between functional components and hooks are that a `functional component returns JSX` and a `custom hook returns business logic`.

First of all react does not render boolean values in JSX so you have to do a conditional rendering to show the difference between the two states of `isFirstRender`.

```
export function App() {
  const isFirstRender = useIsFirstRender();
  
  return(
    <div>
      <p>This is or is not the first render: { isFirstRender ? 'is' : 'is not' } </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Second one you have to change the `useRef` hook with a `useState` hook in your custom hook `useIsFirstRender`. The reason for that is, that a value change in a useRef hook does not trigger a re-rendering of the component, which is using your custom hook.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function useIsFirstRender(): boolean {
  // change useRef to useState
  const [isFirstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);

  // useEffect runs once after the component is registered, 
  // because of the empty dependency array (second argument in the useEffect call)
  useEffect(() => {
    setFirstRender(false);
  }, [])
    
  return isFirstRender;
}
```

FYI: With this custom hook implementation, your component will return for the first rendering `isFirstRender` as true and for upcoming rendering as false.

Answer (score 0):

1. `useIsFirstRender` is a custom React hook, not a function component.
2. [Boolean (*and null and undefined*) values are ignored in JSX](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored), so if you would like to render them then they need to be converted to something that is renderable. You can JSON stringify boolean values or render anything else that is valid JSX.
3. React refs can be mutated at any time *during* the render cycle, for your sanity's state you will generally want to treat React refs as immutable references much like you do React state and props. This means you won't want to change a ref's value as an *unintentional* side-effect. Use the `useEffect` hook to update them.

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export function useIsFirstRender(): boolean {
  const firstRender = useRef<boolean>(true);

  // Mounting effect to update ref at the end of the initial
  // render cycle
  useEffect(() => {
    firstRender.current = false;
  }, []);

  return firstRender.current;
}
```

```
export function App() {
  const isFirstRender = useIsFirstRender();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        This is the first render: {JSON.stringify(isFirstRender)} 
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

or

```
export function App() {
  const isFirstRender = useIsFirstRender();
  
  return(
    <div>
      <p>
        This {isFirstRender ? "is" : "is not"} the first render.
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Beware

Beware that it has generally become quite a React anti-pattern to use "isMounted"/"firstRender" checks, and the addition of React 18's `StrictMode` component's [Ensuring Reusable State](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state) check will certainly create some confusion for you if you are unaware that it mounts the component twice and takes the state of the first mounting. This is a non-production check that helps ensure you don't have leaky/problematic side-effects, i.e. that they are properly cleaned up.

I'm sure the code in your post is a "toy component" for learning purposes, but in actual apps you'll likely not want to do that. Use effect's correctly, including cleaning them up when the components rerender or unmount.